Creating an sqlalchemy hybrid_property that read into a property dictionary value
I have a property (parsing in the sample below) that return a dictionary.
I want to be able to filter query results based on a value inside that dictionary.
I tried to follow this response.
I have the following (simplified) code:
class Document(Base):

    @property
    def parsing(self) -> Optional[dict]:
        # very simplified code, this involve more python code and can't be easily a sqlalchemy expression
        if not self.a_dictionary:
            return None
        return self.a_dictionary

    @hybrid_method
    def get_info(self) -> Optional[str]:
        if not self.parsing:
            return None
        return self.parsing["info"]
    
    @get_info.expression
    def get_info(self) -> String:
        return cast(self.parsing["info"], String)


But when I try to use the expression in a query, something like:
query = Document.query(...).filter(Document.get_info().in_(info_list))


I get that error: 'property' object is not subscriptable caused by the f.parsing["info"] bit.
Is hybrid property and expression really what I should use ? How to fix that?
